# Generacion de de columna en Excel con java sin perder formato (poi)

Tags: java, apache-poi

llevo un par de dias buscando la manera de generar un excel desde java con el formato correcto. Tengo que realizar una tabla con sus nombres de columnas y arriba del nombre de las columnas deberia de poner un titulo. EL problema es que si en la primera columna se agrega un titulo se pierde el formato que tengo de las columnas de las tablas. Quiero conseguir utilizar un formato solo para esa columna del titulo y que no afecte a la tabla que tengo justo debajo.Esto que os pongo debajo si no pongo la tabla justo debajo me sale correctamente cogiendo varias celdas pero al ponerlo con la tabla me introduce todos los datos que tengo puesto del titulo en una celda lo que hace que la tabla no quede correctamente. Por otro lado tambien quiero que aparezca con el formato que aparece la primera columna de la tabla pero solo consigo que me haga el formato para toda la columna hasta el final y que no se como puedo ajustarlo a las celdas que utiliza la tabla.

```
        // Esto seria mi titulo 
        HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short)0);
          row.setHeight((short) 600);
          HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) row.createCell((short) 1);
          cell.setCellValue("Este es el titulo de la tabla"); 

          //esto seria el nombre de cada columna 
            HSSFRow headerRow = sheet.createRow(rowIndex++);
            List<String> headerValues = ReportExcel
                    .getTableHeaderPedidos();
            HSSFCell headerCell = null;

for (int i = 0; i < headerValues.size(); i++) {
                headerCell = headerRow.createCell(i);
                headerCell.setCellStyle(style);
                headerCell.setCellValue(headerValues.get(i));
            }
```

Un saludo y gracias por vuestro tiempo .[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar lo siguiente

```
int start-col = 0; //para ser row 1
int end-col = 0; // para ser row 1
int start-cell = 0; // para ser A1 
int end-cell = 7;// para ser H1
sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(start-col,end-col,start-cell,end-cell));
```

eso es para hacerle merge a las celdas.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y tu tiempo. Me ha salido correctamente el titulo de arriba pero me recoge en la columna cero .me recoge cuatro columnas en una .